# Css set gradient image background with pseudo element

Tags: css, css-selectors, background-image

I want that the image background (in pseudo before) covers all content modal, with this code only covers the content in the height of 200px. Is it possible that?

```css
.modal {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 25px 40px 15px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    position: relative;
}
.modal:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 79, 137, .3) 0%, rgba(255, 199, 150, .3) 100%);
    opacity: 0.3; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="modal">
     <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your goal, you should insert another div as a wrap content. Check the code below:

```css
.modal {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.modal__wrap {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 25px 40px 15px; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.modal__wrap::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 79, 137, .3) 0%, rgba(255, 199, 150, .3) 100%);
    opacity: 0.3; 
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal__wrap">
       <div class="content">
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem was with the position relative in the parent element that had max-height.